# what does the total hits mean without specify track_total_hits=true?

Tags: elasticsearch

When send query to elasticsearch, I can get a response which has a `hits->total` like below:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
...
```

I think the value inside total indicates the count of document matched the query. However the value is not accurate unless I specify `track_total_hits=true` in the query. The question is what the value mean if I don't specify `track_total_hits`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This value is configured in: index.max_result_window.
10000 is the default

For performance reason, this value is sent when es found more than max_result_window documents.